# NextJS, MongoDB Realm, Apollo Example?

Tags: mongodb, next.js, apollo, apollo-client, mongodb-realm

Our project which we actually developed in ReactJS, we are currently moving to NextJS.

Now we have the problem that our original method in ReactJS using MongoDB Realm and Apollo(GraphQL) to retrieve data does not work in NextJS due to the need of SSG and SSR.

After a long time of trying and searching for examples and introductions, we unfortunately haven’t found a solution yet. Now the question: Has anyone already done this or an example project that builds on NextJS, MongoDB Realm and Apollo(GraphQL)?

In case of need we can also use the SWR library. But we haven’t found any helpful (including SSG and SSR) and official examples explicitly for Realm.

Comment: Is your whole setup using lambdas? Or do you have a separated backend / frontend setup?

Comment: We have a separated backend / frontend setup.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Then I do not exactly understand your problem. Apollo Client works great with Next.js, what kind of problems are you running into?

Comment: Were not able to setup a project with Realm Authentication and Apollo, not technically  but more skillbased. So we ask for a example to learn from.